# Using jQuery to POST Form Data to an ASP.NET ASMX Web Service

Tags: jquery, web-services, post, asmx

I try to develop a simple login form where submit button post form data to my method in asmx file. 
The problem is that I get error as soon I try to post from inside a forms tags. 
**Posting outside form tags works fine.**
I have provided a simplified example of my problem:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#submitOutsideForm").click(function () {
        AjaxPost();
    });

    $("#submitInsideForm").click(function () {
        AjaxPost();
    });
});

function AjaxPost() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dummyWS.asmx/HelloToYou",
            data: "{'name': '" + $('#name').val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                AjaxSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Exception in ajaxCall2Func: " + e.name + ".\n Error messege: " + e.message);
    }
}

function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    alert(result.d);
}

function AjaxFailed(result) {
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
</script>  
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: 
<input id="name" />

<form id="form1" runat="server" style="border:1px solid green;">
<div>
    <label for="email">some other form controls</label>
</div>
<input id="submitInsideForm" type="submit" value="Submit Inside Form" />
</form>
<input id="submitOutsideForm" type="submit" value="Submit Outside Form" />
</body>
</html>
```

On server side I have this simple dummy WebService

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/dummyWS.cs" Class="dummyWS" %>
```

…and code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class dummyWS : System.Web.Services.WebService {

  [WebMethod()]
  public string HelloToYou(string name)
  {
      return "Hello " + name;
  }
}
```

Comment: result.status = 0  result.statusText  Not much help there.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your HelloToYou Method as static.

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string HelloToYou(string name)
{
   return "Hello " + name;
}
```